# Is AppCompat necessary when solely working with OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm a bit new to Android, and I was trying to create a simple game with OpenGL ES, and I was wondering if you really need appCombat, because I also manage the whole UI from opengl.
According to my understanding, in this scenario, appCombat would not have any function, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCompact is NEVER required/necessary. It depends of what you're targeting to. For example in my Apps I don't use any AppCompact even if my Apps have normal graphic interfaces (I mean: non-OpenGL). In your case you're using only Opengl, so it is not necessary.

Comment: but would it still be possible to have backwards compatibility?

Comment: You said the WHOLE graphic interface is made using OpenGL, so you don't need backward compatibility for Activities, Fragments, Text Views, etc... You only have to assure backward compatibility for OpenGL methods.